# How can I tidy up my install script keeping only what is used?

Tags: python, pip

We use pip for installations and now I want to clean it so that only the packages that are used are installed. Is it an acceptable strategy to scan my python files in the python project using pycharm and removing the packages which have no used imports or could that possibly go so wrong that a delete an installation that is actually used?

My install script is the following.

```
--find-links=http://pypi.sys.kth.se/local/

# Git support for setuptools
setuptools-git==1.0

Django==1.6.2
django-autoslug==1.6.1
django-cas==KTH-2.0.3
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
South==0.8.4
Pillow==2.3.0
pysolr==2.0.15
django-haystack==1.2.7
django-pagination==1.0.7
Whoosh==2.4.1
markdown2==2.1.0
suds==0.4
python-dateutil<2.0
# for timezone information
pytz<=2013d

django-plainpasswordhasher==0.3

# Infrastructure
python-memcached==1.53
pymongo==2.7.1


# You also need this.. MySQL-python==1.2.3c1

# for iCalendar support (deprecated and slow!)
vobject==0.8.1c

# for iCalendar support
icalendar==3.5

# sane advanced http client (need to support file upload etc)
requests==1.2.1


# for async task handling (for now using simple db backend)
# note this imples amqplib, anyjson, django-celery, django-picklefield, kombu, ordereddict, pyparsing, python-dateutil that we do not explciitly list here.
django-celery==3.1.10
# And Celery monitoring
flower

# Be specific about celery version.
celery==3.1.13

# And pyparse
pyparsing==1.5.7
html2text==3.200.3 # to convert html to (markup) text in mails etc
django-rosetta==0.7.4

diff-match-patch>=20110725

django-compressor==1.4

# note jsmin 2.0.4 was breaking widget.js etc.
jsmin==2.0.2 

# For coverage testing
#coverage

# For nose test runner
nose==1.3.4
django-nose==1.2
mock

#VCR for python
vcrpy==1.0.2

freezegun==0.2.2

phonenumbers==7.0.1

# Monitoring
newrelic==2.34.0.29

# Fileserver requirements
flask>=0.10
httmock==1.2.2
beaker>=1.6.4
```

Comment: I think this is referred to as a pip "requirements file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, your approach sounds reasonable, but there is really no guarantee that it will work for every code base.

The real solution is to make sure you have adequate test  coverage in the first place; then, you can make the change, run the test suite(s), and find with reasonable confidence whether the change broke anything.